# C 2 dimensional array in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays, variables, multidimensional-array

Im new to Objective-c, and what im trying to do is to create a 2 dimensional array of integers.

I know i can use C, in the following way:

```
int levelData[3][4] = {{1,1,1,1}, {1,0,0,1}, {1,1,1,1}};
```

Thing is, i want other other classes to be able to acces this data, so i have to include this variable in the header file, this is where the problem is:

declaring as `int **levelData, int levelData[3][4]` or whatsoever doesnt work.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, i had a static initializer. You cant use those in combination with this.

Answer (score 2):

in your .h file you write

```
extern int levelData[3][4];
```

in your .m/.c file you write

```
int levelData[3][4]= {{1,1,1,1},{1,0,0,1},{1,1,1,1}};
```

EDIT:

at any rate it is better to avoid global variables altogether and instead pass it as a parameter or have it is a ivar in your objective-c class. This avoids strange hard to see dependencies between modules e.g. if a function takes levelData as argument it is clear that the function operates on that argument however by having it global, you can't see easily what a function is using.

Comment: I get an other error: 
Undefined symbols:
  "_levelData", referenced from:
      _levelData$non_lazy_ptr in Game.o
     (maybe you meant: _levelData$non_lazy_ptr)
ld: symbol(s) not found

Comment: You need to make sure that the .m/.c file where you define levelData is linked together with Game.o